# How can i open terminal in mac from the folder

Tags: macos, terminal, spotlight

Is there something way  to open "terminal" like Windows for Mac OS?. In window we can open the terminal direct from the folder. But in Mac i can't open from finder.Have to do from Spotlight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to your keyboard settings>shortcuts. In the *services* category scroll down to "Files and Folders". Tick the box for "New Terminal at Folder" (there should be an option similar to that if you use an alternative terminal like iTerm2). Now, when you are in finder, go to the menu and click Finder > Services > New Terminal Window Here.

You could also make a keyboard shortcut for it back in the shortcut settings where you just came from.

Comment: If you have the "Path Bar" shown (View > Show Path Bar). You can Right Click on any element to get an Open In Terminal option